# checking for two optionals content before calling a method

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I have a methodC() that takes two non Optional parameters both of which are wrapped and returned from other two methods called before.

```
Optional<String> s1Optional = methodA();
Optional<String> s2Optional = methodB();
```

method C definition :

```
private Optional<String> methodC(String s1, String s2){
    return Optional.ofNullable("abc");
}
```

I don't want to use s1Optional.get() and s2Optional.get() as the parameters to the methodC() as it defeats the sole purpose of using Optional.

I know that I can use

```
s1Optional.map(s1 -> methodC(s1, s2Optional).orElseGet(Optional.get());
```

to get a valid return from methodC() only when s1Optional is not empty, but the requirement is that I should do the same for s2Optional.
ie, I should check for both s1Optional and s2Optional to execute methodC.

I understand that it is not always required to use Optionals, but i was just playing around and would like to know if this is possible even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but I think you can just nest the map method calls to achieve what you want.

```
s1Optional.map(
    s1 -> s2Optional.map(s2 -> methodC(s1, s2).orElse("")));
```

This looks quite ugly though. Why not just check if `s1Optional` and `s2Optional` both have values first?

```
if s1Optional.isPresent() && s2Optional.isPresent() {
    anotherMethod(s1Optional.get(), s2Optional.get());
}
```